# Insert each data different rows PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 10 inputs with the same name, and i'm trying to insert them in each rows 
but i'm not sure how should i do that, i searched on google to see if there's any answers but failed.

i hope i explained clearly.

My codes are below:

TQ

I loop my inputs with PHP

```
for($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++){
    print '
    <tr>
                <td><input class="form-mod" type="text" name="sn[]"/></td>
                <td><input class="form-mod" type="text" name="ename[]"/></td>
                <td><input class="form-mod" type="text" name="hrs[]"/></td>
                <td><input class="form-mod" type="text" name="sales[]"/></td>
                <td><input class="form-mod" type="text" name="wages[]"/></td>
                <td ><input class="form-mod" type="text" name="inc[]"/></td>

            </tr>
    ';
}
```

PHP CODE

```
    if(isset($_POST['submited'])){
    $rows = array( array($_POST['pc'],$_POST['wn'],$_POST['from'],$_POST['to'],$_POST['sn'],$_POST['ename'],$_POST['hrs'],$_POST['sales'],$_POST['wages'],$_POST['inc'] )


 );

    $args = array_fill(0, count($rows[0]), '?');

    $query = "INSERT INTO wages (program_code,week_no,`from`,`to`,serial_no,name,hrs,sales,wages,incentive) VALUES (".implode(',', $args).")";
    $stmt = $dbo->prepare($query);

    foreach ($rows as $row) 
    {
       $stmt->execute($row);
    } 


    if(!$stmt->rowCount() >= '1'){
        print "unsuccessfully insert";
    }else{
        print "successfully inserted";
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

i have revised the code that @Vitor Lima type. i remove this code ""`implode(',', $row)`"" and replace it with `?,?,?,?` and it worked. but if i enter only 2 rows with values in the input page it will still insert the remaining 8 to the database, so 2 rows with values and 8 are empty. any idea how to overcome that

```
if(isset($_POST['submited'])){
    for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++){
        $row = array($_POST['pc'], $_POST['wn'], $_POST['from'], $_POST['to'],
                     $_POST['sn'][$x], $_POST['ename'][$x], $_POST['hrs'][$x],
                     $_POST['sales'][$x], $_POST['wages'][$x], $_POST['inc'][$x]);

        $query = "INSERT INTO wages (program_code, week_no,`from`,`to`,serial_no, 
               name,hrs,sales,wages,incentive) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $dbo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($row);

        if(!$stmt->rowCount() >= '1'){
            print "unsuccessfully insert";
        }else{
            print "successfully inserted";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting ?  I think you should make a loop in the PHP script (just like you made in your page) and insert one by one.

Comment: it outputs the word 'Array to string conversion'

Comment: @Jonathan Array to string conversion errors occur when you try to output arrays. PHP only knows how to output string-like values (i.e. strings, numbers, etc.). If you want to output an array you have to format it in some way.

Comment: The prepared statement should must definitely NOT be declared inside of the loop.

Comment: and `rowCount()` does not return a string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for your page: the input's names have `[]`, it means they will be passed as an array to the server, so, for example, `$_POST['sn']` will be an array with ten positions (you can use var_dump to certify...)

So, in your PHP script, you should make a loop, something like that

```
if(isset($_POST['submited'])){

    $stmt = $dbo->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO wages
         (program_code, week_no,`from`,`to`,serial_no, name, hrs, sales, wages, incentive)
         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        );

    for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++){
        $row = array($_POST['pc'], $_POST['wn'], $_POST['from'], $_POST['to'],
                     $_POST['sn'][$x], $_POST['ename'][$x], $_POST['hrs'][$x],
                     $_POST['sales'][$x], $_POST['wages'][$x], $_POST['inc'][$x]);
   
        $stmt->execute($row);
    
        if(!$stmt->rowCount() >= '1'){
            print "unsuccessfully insert";
        }else{
            print "successfully inserted";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it outputs 'Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'John' in 'field list' is it bcoz of the backticks bcoz 'from' & 'to' are reserve words

Comment: i replace `implode(',', $row) to ?,?,?,?` and it worked. add `if(!empty($_POST['sn'][$x])){ query here }` after the loop so it wont insert empty rows. Thx @Vitor Lima

Comment: The prepared statement should must definitely NOT be declared inside of the loop.

Comment: @mickmackusa Hi! The query depends on the variable row, which has a different value at each iteration of the loop... Do you have an alternative? I would be glad to know it and maybe improve my answer, or even even up vote yours, in case you think that it is worth writing your own answer (:

Comment: Ah, now I see that you are not using a prepared statement properly and the query is unstable/insecure.  You need to be using placeholders/parameters and binding the values to those parameters.  In other words, you need to implode a bunch of `?` so that `execute()` feeds those values into where the `?` are.  (like Jonathan said ~6 years ago)

Comment: Yes, I knew about the `?`. Thank you for your comments. I have updated the answer.